# Counting the amount of object with the same value in another column

Tags: sql, database, select, count, window-functions

I want to count the amount of an occurrance the reattacht that the row back and couldn't find any good way to do it.

So 1 table would look like

```
 id | value

 1. a
 2. a
 3. b
 4. a
 5. b
 6. b
 7. c
 8. c
 9. a
```

which I would like to result in:

```
 id | value | count

 1. a,  4
 2. a,  4
 3. b,  3
 4. a,  4
 5. b,  3
 6. b,  3
 7. c,  2
 8. c,  2
 9. a,  4
```

I can only find answers with group by so any help is appreciated. This should also be matched to another table so if the result is joinable that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your RDBMS support window functions, no need to join: you can just do a window count:

```
select t.*, count(*) over(partition by value) cnt from mytable t
```

Comment: Can I also add an additional where statement such as length(value)>5?

Comment: @R.vW: yes, just add a `where` clause to the query. Since we are partitioning by `value` anyway, this will not cause issues.

Comment: And  if I where to add a count on a condition clause for the id?

Answer (score 2):

```
select t.id, t.value, tmp.cnt
from your_table t
join
(
  select value, count(*) as cnt
  from your_table
  group by value
) tmp on tmp.value = t.value
```